# How to set custom meta data for feature at multiple-cucumber-html-reporter?

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I have a problem with creating custom meta data in multiple-cucumber-html-reporter.

[Here](https://wswebcreation.github.io/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter/custom-metadata/index.html) is a example of custom meta data.

How to set custom meta data for cucumber features?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late perhaps, but I ran into the same question recently.

You have to parse the option in the arguments passed to the `report.generate()`
So in my case it looks something like:

```
report.generate({
    customMetadata: true,
    displayDuration: true,
    durationInMS: true,
    jsonDir: '/jsonpath',
    reportPath: '/reportpath',
    metadata: [{
      name: 'Column title',
      value: 'Column value'
    }],
    customData: {
      title: 'Run info',
      data: [{
          label: 'Feature',
          value: 'feature_name'
        },
        {
          label: 'Execution Start Time',
          value: 'start_time'
        },
        {
          label: 'Execution End Time',
          value: 'end_time'
        },
      ]
    }
});
```

More info can be found at:
[Multiple Cucumber HTML Reporter on GITHUB](https://github.com/wswebcreation/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter/blob/master/README.MD#pageTitle)

Comment: I have the same issue, i am using with wdio, but this method doesn't seem to work. are there any other changes i need to do? other than passing the value to the generate(). ?